# Who can reuse existing Power automate Flow to be called inside a Power Apps

Tags: office365, power-automate, power-platform

Using the Office 365 admin account, i created a new Power Automate Flow to be called from Power App, the power automate flow will mainly set unique permissions on the lists' items using the Office 365 admin account, as follow:-

[image]

and i am calling this flow from a Power app created by the same Office 365 admin account, as follow:-

[image]

so my question is, can any user (non-admin user) create a power apps and call the above flow which was created by the office 365 admin? in other words can the non-admin user perform actions that he/she are not authorized to perform by calling the Power automate flow created by the office 365 admin? or this will not be the case, and the Flow created by the Office 365 admin can not be called inside power apps created by non-admin users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things.

1. When you create flow, it will be visible/available only to you. so no other user can access this flow unless you [share this flow](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web-development/9781839213793/9/ch09lvl1sec34/sharing-a-flow-with-run-only-permissions) or make someone co-owner of this flow.
2. Under whose context you have set flow to run, under [running user or always run under some admin user's context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-team-flows). If it is under normal user's context and if that user doe not have access to resources flow will fail. But if you set to run always as Admin then flow will execute as Admin ran it.
3. In addition there is something called [connection references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/create-connection-reference) been used in flows. Take a look at that as well